# Is sending a successful GET request on a resource is like downloading the resource?

Tags: http, server, performance-testing, stress-testing

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to simulate multiple users on my server (stress test + performance test).

Real users click on a button which make them download a resource (generated PDF file). To simulate the same action, is it sufficient to send a GET request on this resource?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Are they downloading a PDF file from the file system?

Is the PDF file generated on the fly via a server side process?

They are quite different scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your insight @Adrian Brand. These are generated PDF files.

Comment: Are you asking, does a browser use GET to download a file, when clicking on a button. Well, that depends on what the button does. Could also be POST.

Comment: Hello @hyde, let my clarify my question, sorry if it was not clear enough. I know for sure that the browser is sending a GET request. I retrieved the adress and parameters and am now sending the same GET request with a stress test tool (and it returns 200). I would like to know if it simulated the same server activity than the real user downloading the PDF from his browser.

Comment: You could use something like Ethereal to see what all the browser sends to the server, and what your test script sends to the server, and compare. The GET request will be the same no matter how you send it (browser or script), but server could be on different state depending on what happened before the GET (such as, user having logged in, different users having access to different files).

Comment: Thanks for this advice, I am going to try this.

Answer (score 0):

Download a http stress testing tool and configure it to point to your resource.

This is going to be different for your OS so read a few good article like this.

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use